# This is a request for my web Development programming class, for a PHP Script for checking the validity of an email address

Tags: php

I have reviewed the page on here that is A PHP for checking email addresses. It didn't help me at all.
*"Write a PHP script that testes whether an e-mail address is input correctly. Verify that the input begins with a series of characters, followed by the @ character, another series of character, a period (.) and a final series of characters. Test the program, using both valid and invalid e-mail addresses."* 
This is what I have, however when I pull up the site on my localhost, the page is blank.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<!-- Fig.19.8: PHP script for email verification. -->
<!-- html with a php email verification -->
<html>
    <head>
    <title></title>
    <style type = "text/css">
         p          { margin: 0px; }
         .error     { color: red }
         p.head     { fong-weight: bold; margin-top: 10px; }
      </style>
    </head>
    <body>

    <?php
        /*
            * PHP Test Script - How to check if a email address is valid using regular expressions
        */

        //A valid email address
        $email = "mycollegeemail@university.edu";

        //the pattern is "any letter or number followed by @ followed by any letter or number
        //followed by . followed by 2-4 letters and maybe another . (for tlds like co.ru)
        $okay = preg_match(
            '/^[A-z0-9_\-]+[@][A-z0-9_\-]+([.][A-z0-9_\-]+)+[A-z.]{2,4}$/', $email
        );
    if(!(filter_var($a, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)))

        //An invalid email address
        $email = "email[at]example[dot]com";

        //the pattern is "any letter or number followed by @ followed by any letter or number
        //followed by . followed by 2-4 letters and maybe another . (for tlds like co.ru)
            $okay = preg_match(
                '/^[A-z0-9_\-]+[@][A-z0-9_\-]+([.][A-z0-9_\-]+)+[A-z]{2,4}$/', $email
        );
if(!(filter_var($a, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)))
    ?>

    </body>
</html>
```

I tried it another way, however, that one did show me the heading and the box where I put the email in and the big grey button 'Validate'. I put in a fake email and it didn't do anything.

Thanks in advance.

### Mereinid

EDIT- Here is my original one that at least pulled the page up.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset= "utf-8">
 <title>Email Validation</title>
      <style type = "text/css">
         p          { margin: 0px; }
         .error     { color: red }
         p.head     { fong-weight: bold; margin-top: 10px; }
      </style>
</head>
    <body>

        <form method = "post" >
        <h1>Enter and email address</h1>
            <p><label>Email:

    <input email = "email" type = "text" size = "25" maxlength = "45">
        </lable></p>

    <p><input type = "submit" value = "Submit"></p>

    <?php 

            if(!validate_email($_POST['email']))
        {
            die("This email address is incorrect");
        }
    ?> 

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: That regular expression is wrong. `bob@fancy.museum` is potentially a valid email address. So is `o'malley@lucky.ie`. `$okay` seems entirely pointless here anyways. The old RFC822 email address validator is a complex beast. Just check for an `@` and then try to deliver it.

Comment: You can cheat and use the `filter_var()` function and supply the `FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL` flag, but I'm guessing you're supposed to write a regex of your own

Comment: At this point in the class I really don't care what I use, I have two weeks left. Even if I bomb the final I'll still pass with my current 94.83. I just want it tell me that I have entered a wrong email when I enter...say bugsbunny@donald.uk...lol. WHen I enter an email now, I get nothing. lol

Answer (score 0):

**General remark:**

A blank page when using PHP usually means invalid code, syntax error, or nothing being output.  Check your error_log (assuming your PHP runs on Apache here).  Or, you are not outputting anything in your code.

**Your specific case:**

Here, you define $okay as the result of preg_match. (http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php).

> preg_match() returns 1 if the pattern matches given subject, 0 if it
>   does not, or FALSE if an error occurred.

So $okay contains either 1, 0 or FALSE (see the note on using === operator).  In your code you do nothing with $okay.  Look at the first example in the page:

```
<?php
// The "i" after the pattern delimiter indicates a case-insensitive search
if (preg_match("/php/i", "PHP is the web scripting language of choice.")) 
{
    echo "A match was found.";
} else {
    echo "A match was not found.";
}
?>
```

See?  That example does something with the result.  Your code does not.

Then your usage of filter_var (http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) is wrong too.  The value of $a is not defined.  And you do not specify anything to do with the if condition.  Again look at the examples in the filter_var page, you will see how to use it in an if statement.

So add some echo statements in your code, these functions do not output anything by default, they just return some value you have to check on.

Comment: And check the related posts, this has been discussed over and over again!